# l.s.c. envelope of integral problems

Tags: functional-analysis

I hope you can help me with some advice to know the l.s.c. envelope of the following functional defined over $L^4(-1,1)$ by

\begin{equation*}
F(u)=\int_{-1}^{1}t^4 |u'(t)|^4 dt, 
\end{equation*}
if $u\in W^{1,4}(-1,1)$, or $\infty$ otherwise, with respect to the $L^4(-1,1)-$topology.

First, we know that $F$ is l.s.c, which is equivalent to prove that $f(t)=t^4|u'(t)|^4$ is convex and l.s.c. I'm not sure if $f$ is convex, then I don't know if the l.s.c. envelope is equal to $F$.

Then I don't know what I must do :(

I have a result:

If $f$ is verifying that there exist $c_1,c_2>0$ such that $f(t)\geq c_1 t^4 - c_2$, then the l.s.c. envelope concides with $\int_{-1}^1 f^{**}(t)dt$, where $f^{**}$ is the convex and l.s.c. envelope of $f$.

To begin, I don't know which $c_1$ I can take (and apply the result).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is a lsc. envelope?

Comment: is the infimun of the set $\{G:L^4(-1,1)\rightarrow R: G\leq F\, and\, G \,is\, weakly\, l.s.c\}$